# how to put string in typeahead bootstrap 4 angular 2 v5

Tags: angular, bootstrap-typeahead

i have 2 problems with my typeahead

first when i selected a object in my typeahead list , i get in my field the correctly string BUT in my Form i have a object

this is my input

```
<input formControlName=SEARCHMARQUE_VEHICULE type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Marque" [ngbTypeahead]="typeaheadHttp.searchMarqueVoiture" [inputFormatter]="typeaheadHttp.formatterMarqueVoitureInput" (selectItem)="selectedMarqueVoiture($event)"[resultFormatter]="typeaheadHttp.formatterMarqueVoiture">
```

this is my formatters

```
public formatterMarqueVoiture = (x: { NOM_MARQUE: string }) => x.NOM_MARQUE;
public formatterMarqueVoitureInput = (x: { NOM_MARQUE: string }) => x.NOM_MARQUE;
```

[image]

and this is my object in my form

i don't understand why i have a object when i asked a string type with my formatter

SEARCHMARQUE_VEHICULE: Object { ID_MARQUE: "mercedes", NOM_MARQUE: "Mercedes-Benz" }

so my question is how can i get just the string in my form ?

and my second question is

when a get de data with API i need to put in my form

but when i want to put a data in my formControlName=SEARCHMARQUE_VEHICULE , this one does not appear in field typeahead but it is in my form when i make a console.log()

i don t understand why and i need your help for that

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

we need just make a condition in formatter

```
public formatterMarqueVoitureInput = (x:any ) => { (typeof x === 'object') ? x=x.NOM_MARQUE : x=x; return x};
```

thanks for the unvote